# SQL Server 2012 concurrency insertion logic checking

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, sql-server-2012

Requirements:

- User can buy any number of count they wish for any package with a random generated point amount for user
- When the sum of count reach a certain number (eg: 10000) the package is closed and the last one who buy the package get the package
- If the last user buy package that is more than 10000, the remaining will not be inserted

My question is: let's say they are thousands of users appears to buy the last count of same package at exact same time, will this work exactly as expected?

Let's say we are now at package 1 with sum of count of 9997:

- User 1 to user 100 buy 3 count for package 1
- User 101 to user 200 buy 5 count for package 1
- User 201 to user 300 buy 7 count for package 1

All at the exactly same time.

Can it be sure that the following store procedure will not insert after 10000 sum count?

If it cannot be sure, how can I make it to be cater for the scenario and requirement?

Table

```
UserID PackageID Count  Point
-----------------------------
  1       1        1      3.2
  2       2        3      2.5
  3       1        4      5.1
  2       3        5      6.3
```

Transaction stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertTransaction
    @UserID INT,
    @PackageID INT,
    @Count INT,
    @Point DECIMAL(30, 2)
AS
    DECLARE @Sum INT = ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Count) 
                                FROM [dbo].[Transaction] 
                                WHERE PackageID = 1), 0);

    IF (@Sum + @Count <= 10000)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction] (UserID, PackageID,  Count, Point)
        VALUES (@UserID, @PackageID, @Count, @Point)

        -- Perform other db and update actions
    END
END
ELSE IF (@Sum + @Count > 10000)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @CanInsertCount INT = @Count - (1000 - @Sum);
   DECLARE @CanInsertPoint DECIMAL(30, 2) = @CanInsertCount / @Count * @Point;

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction] (UserID, PackageID, Count, Point)
   VALUES (@UserID, @PackageID, @CanInsertCount, @CanInsertPoint )

   -- Perform other db insert and update actions
END
```

Comment: 2 people vote close. what is the reason for it? mind to share?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!